# WindowsFormsHost ToolTipService

Tags: c#, wpf, windowsformshost

Simple case code for a problem I'm having:

```
<Window x:Class="WFHTooltipEnableTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:wf="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms;assembly=System.Windows.Forms"  
    >
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>                        
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <WindowsFormsHost Name="HostControl">
            <wf:MaskedTextBox x:Name="mtbDate" Mask="00/00/0000"/>
        </WindowsFormsHost>
        <Button Content="Toggle" Grid.Row="1" Click="Button_Click"></Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WFHTooltipEnableTest
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        bool enabled = true;
        public MainWindow() {}
        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            enabled = !enabled;
            ToolTipService.SetIsEnabled(this.HostControl, enabled);
        }
    }
}
```

The button will toggle the value passed to SetIsEnabled.  When false, the thing hosted in the windows forms host control gets disabled.

Can't seem to find any explanation for this behavior.

Comment: What exactly do you want it to do?

Comment: I want to temporarily disable all tooltips in the app when I load a modal dialog.  It seems that tooltips can get triggered in the time between calling the dialog and actually displaying the dialog - which causes the tooltip to remain open until the dialog closes.  I've implemented a solution based on this suggestion: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/98471070-06ee-481e-b586-08b9fb4f15eb/  which works fine for any WPF code.  But if there is a WindowsFormsHost in the heirarchy it becomes visibly disabled (greys out), which is more or less harmless but distracting.